# iOS UIWebView - refresh only part of html file

Tags: ios, uiwebview, refresh, reload

Is there any way to refresh only part of an HTML file displayed in a UIWebView?  For example, if I make changes to a div in the body, is there any way to refresh only the contents of that div tag?  Or do I have to reload the entire file into my UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reload entire HTML file. It is not possible to reload only part of pure HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Using a little bit of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript like this

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML ='update';"];
 NSString *res = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```